# Play framework 2.2 scala onStart doesn't work

Tags: scala, playframework-2.2

I have problem with GlobalSettings in Play framework. The method onStart is not executed. This is my code:

```
package app
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import play.{GlobalSettings, Logger}

object Global extends GlobalSettings {

  val system = ActorSystem("app")
  Logger.info("test1")

  override def onStart(app: play.Application): Unit = {
    super.onStart(app)
    Logger.info("test2")
  }


}
```

In console I can see only test1. Could someone tell me what I doing wrong.

Comment: Firstly, I believe you don't want to have two "test1" messages. The other should be maybe "test2".

Comment: Yes, I do typo because in my code messages are slightly different :).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One issue is what Vidya wrote. Another one is that your Global object is in the "app" package. It should be not according to the documentation:
http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaGlobal

"This object must be defined in the default (empty) package"

And one more issue. My favourite one in Play. You are not importing correct packages. Do this:

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import play.api._
```

Comment: That's an excellent point I missed. Good catch! "*This object must be defined in the default (empty) package and must extend GlobalSettings.*"

Comment: Ok this is correct answer but how now I can get variable from Global by example in controller?

Comment: Don't have Akka system in the Global object. Use "Akka.system" to get it. Check this: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.1/ScalaAkka

Comment: If you don't want to place your Global object in the default package, you can override it in the application.conf: `application.global = app.Global`

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
override def onStart(app: play.Application) {
    super.onStart(app)
    Logger.info("test2")
}
```